# F#unctional Immutable Trie (Prefix Tree)

Tags: beginner, f#, trie

I've created the following implementation of a trie in F# as an effort to learn the language. I would like to know what could be done to make it more idiomatic. Any other pointers are welcome as well.

Of particular interest are:

- Are my tests sufficient? Is there a better way to construct the tests?
- Can the logic for insert be made cleaner?
- To constrain type or not for functions and parameters?
- What remains to be done to classify this as a proper collection?

```fs
type Trie<'T when 'T : comparison> = {
    IsTerminal: bool;
    Children: Map<'T, Trie<'T>>;
}

module Trie =
    let empty = {
        IsTerminal = false;
        Children = Map.empty;
    }

    let rec insert branch trie =
        match branch with
        | [] ->
            { trie with IsTerminal = true; }
        | el::els ->
            let child = 
                match Map.tryFind el trie.Children with
                | Some t -> t
                | None -> empty
            let child' = insert els child
            let children =
                if Map.containsKey el trie.Children
                then Map.remove el trie.Children
                else trie.Children
            let children' = Map.add el child' children
            { trie with Children = children' }

    let rec contains branch trie =
        match branch with
        | [] -> trie.IsTerminal
        | el::els ->
            match Map.tryFind el trie.Children with
            | Some t -> contains els t
            | None -> false

    let rec toSeq trie =
        seq {
            for KeyValue(label, trie) in trie.Children do
                if trie.IsTerminal then yield [label]
                let children = toSeq trie
                for child in children do
                    yield label :: child
        }

    module Test =
        let ``insert can insert char into root`` =
            let result = empty |> insert ['a']
            Map.containsKey 'a' result.Children
        do assert ``insert can insert char into root``

        let ``insert can insert char into multiple levels`` =
            let result = empty |> insert ['a'..'d']
            Map.containsKey 'd' (((result.Children |> Map.find 'a').Children |> Map.find 'b').Children |> Map.find 'c').Children
        do assert ``insert can insert char into multiple levels``

        let ``contains finds branches that exist in tree`` =
            let result = empty |> insert ['a'..'d']
            contains ['a'..'d'] result
        do assert ``contains finds branches that exist in tree``

        let ``contains does not find incomplete branches`` =
            let result = empty |> insert ['a'..'d']
            result |> contains ['a'..'c'] |> not
        do assert ``contains does not find incomplete branches``

        let ``contains does not find extended branches`` =
            let result = empty |> insert ['a'..'d']
            result |> contains ['a'..'e'] |> not
        do assert ``contains does not find extended branches``
```

Comment: module for tests it makes sense to put separately

Comment: Since posting this, I've tried searching for other f# implementation of trie and I'm honestly proud of this code. I hope to get more feedback.

Comment: @psaxton: Just a question: what's the purpose with inserting a branch to a Trie? If for instance inserting ´["A";"to";"tea";"ted";"ten";"i";"in";"inn"]´ shouldn't it be "Trieed" it self?

Comment: `branch` is a poor name choice. I'm trying to keep this implementation generic. If the consumer intends to store individual words (i.e. autocomplete), they would pass in a char array. If a consumer intends to store sentences or phrases (i.e. Markov chain) they could pass in a string array. If the consumer is intending to store bytes (i.e. compression dictionary) they could pass in a byte array. I'm not certain what to call the path in the trie which the inserted array creates, so I chose `branch`. Suggestions are quite welcome. I'm not fond of el::els either.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I've also placed an updated version in a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/psaxton/c6ec6841a63bf0092304787697dc3beb) where I changed from `insert` to `add` to feel more like the other collection types

Comment: @psaxton I may be wrong but in graph theory, these children are generally called edge(s) (not branches), as Trie is a deterministic finite automaton.

Comment: @gerard I'll have to look into that. My mind was thinking branches and leaves like I've seen in tree structures.

Comment: @psaxton just as a side note, I'm not sure if Map is a good way to look up edges, Map is a AVL data structure like a b-Tree, you want O(1) hash style access as the Trie itself is the structure that prevents unnecessary keys/paths being tested. b-trees/AVL are ideal for range scans where want to know closest match etc, a dictionary is probably better suited,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good!  Just a few notes:

> Can the logic for insert be made cleaner?

It's very good already. "helper functions" would make it easier to understand and refactor. Something like:

```
let removeChild el children = 
    if Map.containsKey el children
    then Map.remove el children
    else children

let findChild el children = // left as an exercise :)

let rec insert branch trie =
    match branch with
    | [] ->
        { trie with IsTerminal = true; }
    | el::els ->
        let child = findChild el trie.Children
        let child' = insert els child
        let children = removeChild el trie.Children
        let children' = Map.add el child' children
        { trie with Children = children' }
```

Then you can use the pipe `|>` operator to refactor the `insert` to:

```
    | el::els ->
        let child' = trie.Children |> findChild el  |> insert els
        let children' = trie.Children |> removeChild el |> Map.add el child'
        { trie with Children = children' }
```

Also if you analyze removeChild, you'll realize it can be refactored to just one line

```
let removeChild = Map.remove
```

> What remains to be done to classify this as a proper collection?

A bit more.  You can discover them by refactoring your tests. For example:

```
module Trie = 
    let fromSeq s = insert s empty
    let containsKey key trie = // todo

module Test = 
    let ``insert can insert char into root`` =
        let result = Trie.fromSeq ['a']
        result |> Trie.containsKey 'a'
    do assert ``insert can insert char into root``
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several libraries for writing unit tests in F#. For example:

- [FsUnit](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/)
- [Unquote](http://www.swensensoftware.com/unquote)
- [Fuchu](https://github.com/mausch/Fuchu)

The logic is pretty clear, but there are a couple of comments

1.
Instead of:

```
        let child = 
            match Map.tryFind el trie.Children with
            | Some t -> t
            | None -> empty
```

you can rewrite this code with using [defaultArg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.defaultarg%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

```
        let child = 
            Map.tryFind el trie.Children
            |> defaultArg  <| empty
```

2.
You can use functions from a module [Option](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/options), so..instead:

```
        match Map.tryFind el trie.Children with
        | Some t -> contains els t
        | None -> false
```

better:

```
        Map.tryFind el trie.Children
        |> Option.exists (contains els)
```

Comment: Thanks for the review. I've implemented the changes [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/psaxton/c6ec6841a63bf0092304787697dc3beb) and found ways to clean up some other pieces, such as the child -> child' assignments. I'm researching the [collection types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-collection-types) and will post another review after I feel I have made this feel more like the base collections.